# How to Access attributes from grpc Context.current()?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, protobuf-java

Would it be possible to access context attributes of a grpc call from the rpc method definition?

I have written a Server Interceptor which is something similar to this

```
@Override
public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, final Metadata requestHeaders, ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {

   Context.Key<String> USER = Context.key("USER");
 
  Context ctx = Context.current().withValue(USER, "chandan");
  return Contexts.interceptCall(ctx, call, requestHeaders, next);
}
```

and in the service implementation, I was trying something like

```
Context.Key<String> key = Context.key("USER");
String value = key.get(Context.current())
```

Everytime value was null. However While debugging in intellij I could see those values in the `context.current().keyValueEntries` as

```
CompressedIndex(bitmap=100001000000000000000000000000 Leaf(key=USER value=chandan) Leaf(key=opencensus-trace-span-key value=BlankSpan) )
```

How do I access the Context attributes/What is the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Context.Key` uses reference equality. The `"USER"` string is a debug string used in `toString()` output. You should create the `Key` once and reference that one instance anywhere you need it.

Because `Context.Key` uses reference equality, you can use normal Java visibility restrictions to limit who can access the value, just like you could do with `ThreadLocal`.